# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).makeRed is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, exception, client-side

I want to call custom javascript function with jquery selector but this say Uncaught TypeError: $(...).makeRed is not a function

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h3 id="ch">Hello Wrld</h3>

</body>
</html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.fn.makeRed = function(){
            this.html('welcome to all');
            return this;
    }
});
    $('#ch').makeRed();


</script>
```

Comment: Put the line `$('#ch').makeRed();` inside `$(document).ready(function(){...})` too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling makeRed before it's created on ready State. Put it inside the `});` Here is the fixed snippet. :)

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.fn.makeRed = function(){
            this.html('welcome to all');
            return this;
    }
     $('#ch').makeRed();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h3 id="ch">Hello Wrld</h3>

</body>
</html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```